# What is the difference in how $\mathrm{R}^2$ and $\mathrm{R}$ values are interpreted?

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation, data-analysis

In statistics, there is the $\mathrm{R}$ value for the product moment correlation coefficient and the $\mathrm{R}^2$ value for the coefficient of determination.

In both cases they are described as a scale of correlation, where $0$ is no correlation and $1$ is perfect correlation. However, for a given data set these values are different - for example when $\mathrm{R}=0.8$ the $\mathrm{R}^2=0.64$. How can this be so?

Another layer of confusion is that for the $\mathrm{R}^2$ value, it is said that the value represents the proportion of change in $y$ caused by changes in $x$. For instance, an $\mathrm{R}^2$ value of 0.7 means that 70% of the change in the dependent variable is explained by changes in the independent variable. Is this also true of the $\mathrm{R}$ value? Why or why not?

Comment: You should definitely ask this in http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä Thank you for the link I will post this there

Answer (score 1):

The *sample correlation* $r$ can take values in $(-1,1)$, where
negative values indicate negative linear association between
the two data vectors and positive values indicate positive linear
association. The *sample coefficient of determination* $r^2$ takes values in $(0, 1),$ where larger values indicate increasing
linear association. (The Wikipedia article on correlation has some
nice examples to distinguish 'linear association' from 'association'.)

In software, especially for regression output, $r^2$ is often
written as $R^2$ or `R-sq`. Strictly speaking it just the square
of the correlation, but is often written as a percentage.

However, in simple linear regression, where we are trying to
predict y values from x values, one tends to focus on the
variability of y. Roughly speaking, in that context, one sometimes
says that regression of y on x `explains R percent of the
variability in y'.

This latter interpretation comes from the equation
$$s_{y|x}^2 = \frac{n-1}{n-2} s_y^2(1 - r^2).$$

For example, if $y = b_0 + b_1 x\,$ exactly, then all $(x,y)$ points
fall precisely on a line, $r = \pm 1$ (depending on positive
or negative slope), $r^2 = 1 = 100\%,$ and all of the variation
in y is explained by regression on x.